# Why am i getting the error: list' object has no attribute 'replace'. I need to put my answer in a list without the character \xa0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my code:

```
df_olympics = pandas.read_csv("Olympics_data.csv", sep = ";")

df_olympics.drop(df_olympics.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
df_olympics= df_olympics[(df_olympics[' summer_games_played'] >0) & (df_olympics['winter_games_played'] >0)]
df_olympics['total_medals_won']=(df_olympics[" summer_games_gold_won"])+(df_olympics[" winter_games_gold_won"])
df_olympics=df_olympics[(df_olympics['total_medals_won']==0)]

team_name_list=(df_olympics.loc[:,['team_name',]])
team_name_list = team_name_list.values.tolist()

team_list_name_clean = team_name_list.replace('\xa0', '')
print(team_list_name_clean)
```

The picture:

[image]

Comment: `replace()` is a string method, not a list method.

Comment: Why don't you do the replacement in the dataframe before converting to a list?

Comment: use a list comprehension then call the replace on each element

Comment: I think you want `team_list_name_clean = df_olympics["team_name"].str.replace("\xa0","").tolist()`

Comment: @not_speshal, your answer worked! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
team_list_name_clean = [x.replace('\xa0', '') for x in team_name]
```